# HTML form string error

Tags: php, html, css, xhtml, textarea

When I click the "Send "Request" button, the query string `?req_flag=0` disappears from the URL.
Where am I making a mistake here? I need following URL: `localhost/flavourr/send_req.php?req_flag=0&f_e_mail_add=value`

```
<pre>
<form method="get" action="send_req.php?req_flag=0">
                        <input type="text" name="f_e_mail_add" value="Enter email of your friend" onblur='if (this.value == "") {this.value = "Enter email of your friend";}' onfocus='if (this.value == "Enter email of your friend") {this.value = "";}' size="35" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Send Request" />
                            </form></pre>
```

Comment: You may have to give us more info to go on, like some code for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a hidden value as shown below and remove the '?req_flag=0' from the action attribute.

```
<form method="get" action="send_req.php">
    <input type="text" name="f_e_mail_add" value="Enter email of your friend" size="35" />
    <input type="hidden" id="req_flag" name="req_flag" value="0" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send Request" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your page gets that parameter from another source you can't simply transfer a GET parameter from one page to another. You have to find a way for your new form to include that parameter again before submitting the form.

The easiest way is to store it inside a hidden input element like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="req_flag" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['req_flag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>" />
```