# HTML form problem!

Tags: html, css, forms

Does the text written in the input value of the form get appended to the form action URL if that input field is left empty? if not, then how can we do that?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Related to your other question? [HTML form string error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6779966)

Comment: This is a simple question but I don't think it show be down voted for that. That being said, you would be able to find the answer to this by searching this forum. Before you post a question it's all ways a good idea, other wise some one WILL down vote you for not looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated it will, in the url in will be like `?someKey=&someOtherKey=` you will see that there is no value for ether key just the start of the next. You can force a value in a input by using `value='some default value'` in the HTML this will show to the user and be sent in the `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Hope that this clear it up a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It will be added to the query string in `GET` and in the post values when `POST`ing.